# Subset specific row and last row from data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains data relating to a score of different events. There can be a number of scoring events for one game. What I would like to do, is to subset the occasions when the score goes above 5 or below -5. I would also like to get the last row for each ID. So for each ID, I would have one or more rows depending on whether the score goes above 5 or below -5.  My actual data set contains many other columns of information, but if I learn how to do this then I'll be able to apply it to anything else that I may want to do.

Here is a data set

```
ID Score Time
1    0    0
1    3    5
1    -2   9
1    -4   17
1    -7   31
1    -1   43
2    0    0
2    -3   15
2    0    19
2    4    25
2    6    29
2    9    33
2    3    37
3    0    0
3    5    3
3    2    11
```

So for this data set, I would hopefully get this output:

```
ID Score Time
1   -7    31    
1   -1    43
2    6    29 
2    9    33
2    3    37
3    2    11
```

So at the very least, for each ID there will be one line printed with the last score for that ID regardless of whether the score goes above 5 or below -5 during the event( this occurs for ID 3).

My attempt can subset when the value goes above 5 or below -5, I just don't know how to write code to get the last line for each ID:

```
Data[Data$Score > 5 | Data$Score < -5]
```

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: What do you want to happen to a row that satisfies both conditions? Should it appear once or twice?

Comment: Preferably just once. If it appears twice it isn't an issue, I'm sure there is a way to delete duplicate rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rle` to grab the last row for each ID. Check out `?rle` for more information about this useful function.

```
Data2 <- Data[cumsum(rle(Data$ID)$lengths), ]
Data2
#   ID Score Time
#6   1    -1   43
#13  2     3   37
#16  3     2   11
```

To combine the two conditions, use `rbind`.

```
Data2 <- rbind(Data[Data$Score > 5 | Data$Score < -5, ], Data[cumsum(rle(Data$ID)$lengths), ])
```

To get rid of rows that satisfy both conditions, you can use `duplicated` and `rownames`.

```
Data2 <- Data2[!duplicated(rownames(Data2)), ]
```

You can also sort if desired, of course.

Comment: In your `rbind` code, you could simplify the whole line down to `df[with(df, c(which(Score > 5 | Score < -5), cumsum(rle(ID)$lengths))), ]`

Comment: Whenever I run this code,  get the error 
`1: In Ops.factor(Score, 5) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(Score, -5) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors`

Even though I previously transform Score to numeric : 

`DF <- transform(Table, Score = as.numeric(as.character(Score)))`
 `class(DF$Score)`
`[1] "numeric"`

Comment: @useR How did you read in your data? Make sure that you read it in so that the Score field is not a factor as you need to do numeric comparisons with it.

Comment: I left my computer for the weekend, came back and its now working! Thanks very much. The only issued I face was that the data wasn't grouped together. By that, I mean it printed all of the times when the score was above 5 or below -5, and then it printed the final value for each ID.

I solved this issue by sorting the data frame by grouping the data by ID.

`Data3  <- Data2[order(Data2$ID),]`

Comment: @useR If you want the rows in the same exact order as the original dataframe, then you can sort by the rownames, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a go at it in *data.table*, where `df` is your original data frame.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[df[, c(.I[!between(Score, -5, 5)], .I[.N]), by = ID]$V1]
#    ID Score Time
# 1:  1    -7   31
# 2:  1    -1   43
# 3:  2     6   29
# 4:  2     9   33
# 5:  2     3   37
# 6:  3     2   11
```

We are grouping by `ID`.  The `between` function finds the values between -5 and 5, and we negate that to get our desired values outside that range.  We then use a `.I`  subset to get the indices per group for those.  Then `.I[.N]` gives us the row number of the last entry, per group.  We use the `V1` column of that result as our row subset for the entire table.  You can take unique values if unique rows are desired.

**Note:** `.I[c(which(!between(Score, -5, 5)), .N)]` could also be used in the `j` entry of the first operation.  Not sure if it's more or less efficient.

**Addition:**  Another method, one that uses only logical values and will never produce duplicate rows in the output, is

```
df[df[, .I == .I[.N] | !between(Score, -5, 5), by = ID]$V1]
#    ID Score Time
# 1:  1    -7   31
# 2:  1    -1   43
# 3:  2     6   29
# 4:  2     9   33
# 5:  2     3   37
# 6:  3     2   11
```

Comment: Whenever I try run this code I get the error
`Error in `[.data.frame`(DF, , .I == .I[.N] | !between(Score, -5, 5), by = ID) : 
  unused argument (by = ID)'

Even though ID is definitely a column name:

`> colnames(DF)`
`[1] "ID"         "Score"     "Time" `              `

Comment: @useR Did you run `library(data.table)`?  The package needs to be installed and loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R solution.

```
df[as.logical(ave(df$Score, df$ID,
                  FUN=function(i) abs(i) > 5 | seq_along(i) == length(i))), ]

   ID Score Time
5   1    -7   31
6   1    -1   43
11  2     6   29
12  2     9   33
13  2     3   37
16  3     2   11
```

`abs(i) > 5 | seq_along(i) == length(i)` constructs a logical vector that returns TRUE for each element that fits your criteria. `ave` applies this function to each ID. The resulting logical vector is used to select the rows of the data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution. Not as concise as some of the above, but easier to follow.

```
library(tidyverse)
lastrows  <- Data %>% group_by(ID) %>% top_n(1, Time)
scorerows <- Data %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(!between(Score, -5, 5))
bind_rows(scorerows, lastrows) %>% arrange(ID, Time) %>% unique()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#      ID Score  Time
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1    -7    31
# 2     1    -1    43
# 3     2     6    29
# 4     2     9    33
# 5     2     3    37
# 6     3     2    11
```